# Do not use a triple slash reference for

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use a type declaration file. When using triple slash reference like so:

```
/// <reference path="../declarations.d.ts" />
```

The app builds fine, but I get the above eslint error: `"Do not use a triple slash reference for ../declarations.d.ts, use` import `style instead`(https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/triple-slash-reference/)

If I do use an import:

```
import "../declarations.d.ts"
```

The build fails and the declarations file is being ignored.

I also tried to use `tsconfig.json` to add the file, but that also failed (I'm using NX environment, probably there's some bug with NX)

So only the reference syntax is working, but then I get that es-lint error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My custom declaration file:

```
import '@types/my-react-package';

declare module '@types/my-react-package' {
  export interface PackageProps {
    showPreview?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's `import type "../declarations.d.ts"`

Comment: or `/// <reference types="../declarations.d.ts" />`

Comment: @Dimava nope, the import type syntax you wrote is invalid, you can try it. And the reference is for path not types, anyways the triple slash reference is working properly but I would prefer to do it without complaints from eslint

Comment: erm,
if it's declaration, use ///reference with types instead. try it, will that work?

Comment: also about eslint, please provide link to error docs, intellisence has it iirc, oer error code at lease

Comment: Is that for global types?

Comment: You're right I should provide the link is this: "https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/triple-slash-reference/"
I'll also update my question now with the declaration file I created. It's not for global types, it's for a specific 3rd party package I'm using

Answer (score -2):

Since you want only the types from the declaration file, changing reference from `path` to `types` should help do the trick with build failing because types will be ignored at build time. Ex:

```
/// <reference types="../declarations.d.ts" />
```